# Usar promise é errado (deprecated) hoje em dia?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promises

Bom, trabalho com angular atualmente e sempre tenho dúvida se é errado usar promises ou nao, exemplo. Eu tenho um código que precisa ser async. Primeira função deve validar a permissão de acesso, após validar o status do funcionário e passando por essas validações deve efetuar a chamada para carregar as informações na tela... algo deste tipo

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (this.validatePermission() && this.validateStatus('ACTIVE')) {
    this.showUserDetail(100);
  }
}
```

Fazer com que cada função dessa retorne uma promise me parece errado...

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso, seria Observables ?

Comment: Por que seria errado usar promessas? Não tem nada de errado com elas. Depende do que você precisa fazer. Promessas e observáveis não são totalmente equivalentes, de modo que um não deve ser "trocado" pelo outro sem o devido critério.

Comment: Trabalho com Angular a cerca de 3 anos e nunca vi em projetos Angular nenhum utilização de **Promise** pura (Vanilla),  para isso existe **Observable** e até o **toPromise** que são da bilbioteca **`rxjs`**, pq deveria utilizá-la pura? Pq essas features não atendem seu projeto? `Fazer com que cada função dessa retorne uma promise me parece errado...`, pq acha isso? Se estas funções tendem a ir buscar algum dado em algum servidor, como pretende que as mesmas não sejam assíncronas (Promises ou Observables)??

Comment: Nesse meu caso usar async/await seria a maneira mais fácil de fazer isso, porem sei que existem funções no rxjs como o mergeMap onde eu conseguiria o mesmo resultado. Sempre que falo em usar promise por aqui na empresa surge este assunto de que Promise foi depreciado, mas eu nunca encontrei isso em lugar nenhum... Só encontro que Promise foi substituída por Observable no HttpClinte. Minha dúvida aqui era justamente sobre isso, se mais alguém tem essa visão de que devemos evitar uso de promise e preferir observable, mas pelo que estou vendo é uma opinião errada.

Comment: Não existe isso de `Promise` está depreciado. [Depreciação é outra coisa.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) Talvez não utilizar promessas seja uma convenção da empresa, embora eu a questionaria. Só por curiosidade, `async`/`await` pode quase ser visto como um açúcar sintático para "desempacotar" promessas ([saiba mais](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)). Portanto, `async`/`await` se embasa nas promessas – se promessas fossem depreciadas, `async`/`await` seria, por consequência, depreciado também.

Comment: O padrão do angular é usar observables se seu time usa ele invés de promises acho uma boa idéia seguir